# Find a base of V

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have $V=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3, 2x+2y+z=0\}$, how I find one of it's bases?

So Far i have:
Showing that we have linear independence  $c1(2x)+c2(2y)+c3(z)=0$
 $2c_1= 0$, $2c_2=0$, $c_3=0$, so they are indeed linearly independent. (I have progress correctly, so far?).

2)(A Thought) So the base is $(-2y+2z,y,z)$, an example of it would be: $(-4+8,2,4) = (2,2,4)$?

How I find a base of $V$?

Comment: That is just wrong. Considering your space as a geometric object, what will it be? A line or a plane?

Comment: ain't the space (as a geometric object) a "cube"?

Comment: To clarify: your vector space is $\mathbb{R}^3$ which can be thought of an infinite cube somehow. But I am talking about your set: this is a subspace and is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Yes, i understood my mistake, V is a subspace of R³ so according to that my thought were (1),(2).

Comment: But (1) and (2) are completely wrong. What is the dimension of a plane, i.e. how many different directions you have?

Comment: dimension of plane(x,y) and dimensions of a cube(x,y,z) so how 2x+2y+z is wrong?

Comment: I think you should really look up what basis and dimension in a vector space mean. A plane is $2$ dimensional whereas $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $3$ dimensional, i.e. consider the standard basis. Hence you have to find $2$ basis vectors and you've got only one.

Comment: Well i have understood correctly what a basis mean, i think what gonna make sense is : this exercise also gives me a subspace of W ={(x,y,z)εR³,x+2y+z=0}, so i have to ffind both basis for those 2 subspaces(not their addition).

Answer (score 0):

Setting $z := \mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y := \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, we get $x = -\lambda - \frac{1}{2}\mu$. Written parametrically, you have $$V = \left\{ \lambda\begin{pmatrix} -1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} + \mu\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2}\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} : \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$ Hence a basis would be $$\mathcal{B} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} -1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} -1\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$